# Autocomplete credentials for login form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I created a login form that saves the credentials to the browsers local storage if the user checked the *Remember* checkbox at the time of login.

If the user tries to login again, the user details should get filled in similar to autocomplete; so, if the user types a few letters of his name, the full name and the password should automatically be filled into the form.

I have no backend API for this available, so I need to do it in the front-end.

Storing the data (username, pass) in the local session if the *Remember* checkbox is active works, but the automatic filling does not work. How can I make it work?

My jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mohanacchu/a14Lstqx/1/)

```js
$(function () {
    if (localStorage.chkbx && localStorage.getItem(chkbx) !== '') {
        $('#modal_login_remember').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#modal_login_email').val(localStorage.getItem(usrname));
        $('#modal_login_password').val(localStorage.getItem(pass));
    } else {
        $('#modal_login_remember').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#modal_login_email').val('');
        $('#modal_login_password').val('');
    }

    $('#modal_login_remember').click(function () {

        if ($('#modal_login_remember').is(':checked')) {
            // save username and password
            localStorage.setItem('usrname', $('#modal_login_email').val());
            localStorage.setItem('pass', $('#modal_login_password').val());
            localStorage.setItem('chkbx', $('#modal_login_remember').val());
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('usrname', '');
            localStorage.setItem('pass', '');
            localStorage.setItem('chkbx', '');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <p style="text-align: center"><i>Enter your email ID and password to log in to Help.</i></p>

  <div id="errormsg" style="display: none; color:red;text-align: center; padding-bottom: 1.2rem;">
    Invalid token or login credentials, please log in again.
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="email" id="modal_login_email" name="modal_login_email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="password" id="modal_login_password" name="modal_login_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
  </div>
</div>
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="modal_login_remember" class="custom-control-input" />
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description">Remember me</span>
</label>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="button" onclick="login(document.getElementById('modal_login_email').value,document.getElementById('modal_login_password').value);"
    class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" style="background-color: #19659d; border-color: #19659d;" />
</div>
```

Comment: store a cookie that mark the user as logged in already but never store username and password in plain text in the local storage. this is a very bad idea for security

Comment: @LelioFaieta You're right about password, but how can a "Remember me" checkbox work without saving the username?

Comment: "Remember me" usually fills in the entire username, it doesn't just do auto-complete.

Comment: it works if only one user is supposed to use that browser. Otherwise I agree with you you should ask for the password filling the username with "remember me".